# Can any one de-obfuscator this php code

Tags: decryption, anti-debugging, php

my developer has changed all his contact info and i am unable to contact him
and i want to move my site to another server but because of this obfuscator code in my php script i am unable to move my site can any one please decode this php file
[obfuscator code](https://pastebin.com/TQ1PD4x0)

Answer (score 1):

Every single variable name has been randomized. Unless he gives you the source without the randomized names, you'll have to rename every variable by yourself in your php files if you want to get something that's easily readable.

The best I can do for you is format it and fix some issues with text quotes to make it a little bit more readable.

```
<?php
${"GLOBALS"}["yqyebcv"] = "file_name";
${"GLOBALS"}["ypbgqag"] = "return";
${"GLOBALS"}["nsppyylnqkk"] = "link";
${"GLOBALS"}["njfqrtm"] = "dir";
${"GLOBALS"}["pdicsfrvpn"] = "use";
${"GLOBALS"}["esfuxfpwsnx"] = "file";
${"GLOBALS"}["nwisdeafetc"] = "location";
${"GLOBALS"}["rxsfphe"] = "add";
${"GLOBALS"}["ryjuqyuyytv"] = "type";
${"GLOBALS"}["jbdilpns"] = "t";
${"GLOBALS"}["qyjncgibsx"] = "round";
${"GLOBALS"}["sknxttw"] = "size";
${"GLOBALS"}["bvfnpllyxgs"] = "total";
${"GLOBALS"}["vsgjwjgohjuo"] = "sizes";
${"GLOBALS"}["mmbijie"] = "bklnk_i";
${"GLOBALS"}["jmjkcwrtoljb"] = "bklnk";
${"GLOBALS"}["rvkxbu"] = "i";
${"GLOBALS"}["zdvwmpshlpn"] = "parentsArray";
${"GLOBALS"}["tmjgwmr"] = "url";
${"GLOBALS"}["kiakpghmlj"] = "lower";
${"GLOBALS"}["dvawhj"] = "secure_root";
${"GLOBALS"}["wgzhjucrj"] = "f";
${"GLOBALS"}["otzvpmqy"] = "ext";
${"GLOBALS"}["itzvyk"] = "name";
${"GLOBALS"}["fjwzrfegv"] = "sitename";
${"GLOBALS"}["gcdrnalkkv"] = "table";
${"GLOBALS"}["lukjgrca"] = "result";
${"GLOBALS"}["nafdhnp"] = "id";
${"GLOBALS"}["ljsrydy"] = "c";
${"GLOBALS"}["kzugnpx"] = "return_msg";
${"GLOBALS"}["digfzfma"] = "limit";
${"GLOBALS"}["xytqykr"] = "list";
${"GLOBALS"}["dfmnkulxo"] = "CI";
if (!defined("BASEPATH")) exit("No direct script access allowed");
if (!function_exists("list_categories")) {
    function list_categories()
    {
        ${"GLOBALS"}["skksnbv"] = "list";
        ${"GLOBALS"}["blxubymic"] = "list";
        ${${"GLOBALS"}["skksnbv"]} = array();
        $xbqxrncnji = "list";
        ${${"GLOBALS"}["dfmnkulxo"]} = &get_instance();
        $CI->db->order_by("ord", "DESC")->order_by("id", "DESC")->where("status", "A")->where("child", "N");
        ${$xbqxrncnji} = $CI->db->get("category")->result();
        return ${${"GLOBALS"}["blxubymic"]};
    }
}
$eruyiys = "secure_root";
${$eruyiys} = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
if (!function_exists("list_updates")) {
    function list_updates($limit = 10)
    {
        ${"GLOBALS"}["qgqhjruw"] = "limit";
        $vjcxqhk = "CI";
        $glxvvhyzmsiu = "list";
        ${${"GLOBALS"}["xytqykr"]} = array();
        ${$vjcxqhk} = &get_instance();
        ${$glxvvhyzmsiu} = $CI->db->query("SELECT * FROM updates where status='A' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT " . intval(${${"GLOBALS"}["qgqhjruw"]}))->result();
        return ${${"GLOBALS"}["xytqykr"]};
    }
}
if (!function_exists("list_featured")) {
    function list_featured($limit = 1)
    {
        ${"GLOBALS"}["hnhpfrx"] = "list";
        ${${"GLOBALS"}["xytqykr"]} = array();
        ${${"GLOBALS"}["dfmnkulxo"]} = &get_instance();
        ${${"GLOBALS"}["hnhpfrx"]} = $CI->db->query("SELECT * FROM files where status='A' ORDER BY download,RAND() LIMIT " . intval(${${"GLOBALS"}["digfzfma"]}))->result();
        return ${${"GLOBALS"}["xytqykr"]};
    }
}
${${"GLOBALS"}["kzugnpx"]} = "Contact Admin";
if (!function_exists("cat_type")) {
    function cat_type($id = '')
    {
        ${"GLOBALS"}["vsmrlcpd"] = "CI";
        ${${"GLOBALS"}["ljsrydy"]} = intval(${${"GLOBALS"}["nafdhnp"]});
        ${${"GLOBALS"}["vsmrlcpd"]} = &get_instance();
        $CI->db->where("status", "A")->where("category_id", ${${"GLOBALS"}["ljsrydy"]});
        ${${"GLOBALS"}["lukjgrca"]} = $CI->db->get("files")->num_rows();
        return (${${"GLOBALS"}["lukjgrca"]} == 0 ? "categorylist" : "filelist");
    }
}
if (!function_exists("get_info")) {
    function get_info($id, $table)
    {
        $ujxgciidjl = "list";
        ${"GLOBALS"}["horwwuimlu"] = "id";
        if (!intval(${${"GLOBALS"}["nafdhnp"]})) {
            return false;
        }
        ${$ujxgciidjl} = array();
        ${"GLOBALS"}["ydlpgty"] = "CI";
        ${${"GLOBALS"}["ydlpgty"]} = &get_instance();
        ${${"GLOBALS"}["xytqykr"]} = $CI->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . ${${"GLOBALS"}["gcdrnalkkv"]} . " where id='" . intval(${${"GLOBALS"}["horwwuimlu"]}) . "' ORDER BY id DESC")->result();
        return ${${"GLOBALS"}["xytqykr"]}[0];
    }
}
if (!function_exists("seo_name")) {
    function seo_name($name, $ext, $sitename = '')
    {
        $whufdxlxuk = "f";
        ${"GLOBALS"}["ewlqmgjts"] = "f";
        ${$whufdxlxuk} = str_ireplace(${${"GLOBALS"}["fjwzrfegv"]}, null, ${${"GLOBALS"}["itzvyk"]});
        ${"GLOBALS"}["qbqyeadkml"] = "f";
        if (${${"GLOBALS"}["otzvpmqy"]} != NULL) {
            $slpneqg = "f";
            $srzgnrllcrh = "f";
            ${$srzgnrllcrh} = str_ireplace("." . ${${"GLOBALS"}["otzvpmqy"]}, null, ${$slpneqg});
        }
        $umbqttnpma = "f";
        ${${"GLOBALS"}["qbqyeadkml"]} = str_replace("_", " ", ${${"GLOBALS"}["wgzhjucrj"]});
        ${${"GLOBALS"}["wgzhjucrj"]} = str_replace(" ", " ", ${${"GLOBALS"}["ewlqmgjts"]});
        ${${"GLOBALS"}["wgzhjucrj"]} = str_replace("  ", " ", ${$umbqttnpma});
        return ${${"GLOBALS"}["wgzhjucrj"]};
    }
}
if (${${"GLOBALS"}["dvawhj"]} != "/home/asomi/public_html") {
    $ukcmqyoeta = "return_msg";
    die(${$ukcmqyoeta});
}
if (!function_exists("seo_url")) {
    function seo_url($name, $ext, $sitename = '', $lower = false)
    {
        $klvkiu = "ext";
        $fwddgvaroft = "f";
        ${${"GLOBALS"}["wgzhjucrj"]} = str_ireplace(${${"GLOBALS"}["fjwzrfegv"]}, null, ${${"GLOBALS"}["itzvyk"]});
        if (${$klvkiu} != NULL) {
            $fklszts = "f";
            ${$fklszts} = str_ireplace("." . ${${"GLOBALS"}["otzvpmqy"]}, null, ${${"GLOBALS"}["wgzhjucrj"]});
        }
        $xvyvcssvdb = "f";
        $eirnplcg = "f";
        ${"GLOBALS"}["zjupglec"] = "f";
        ${${"GLOBALS"}["wgzhjucrj"]} = str_replace(" ", "_", ${$fwddgvaroft});
        $jokleqez = "f";
        ${${"GLOBALS"}["wgzhjucrj"]} = str_replace("_", "_", ${${"GLOBALS"}["wgzhjucrj"]});
        ${${"GLOBALS"}["wgzhjucrj"]} = str_replace("___", "_", ${$eirnplcg});
        ${${"GLOBALS"}["wgzhjucrj"]} = str_replace("__", "_", ${${"GLOBALS"}["wgzhjucrj"]});
        ${${"GLOBALS"}["zjupglec"]} = str_replace("(", null, ${${"GLOBALS"}["wgzhjucrj"]});
        ${"GLOBALS"}["rbnfuxpjxqpj"] = "f";
        ${$jokleqez} = str_replace(")", null, ${${"GLOBALS"}["wgzhjucrj"]});
        return (${${"GLOBALS"}["kiakpghmlj"]} ? strtolower(${$xvyvcssvdb}) : ${${"GLOBALS"}["rbnfuxpjxqpj"]});
    }
}
if (!function_exists("get_backlinks")) {
    function get_backlinks($id)
    {
        if (intval(${${"GLOBALS"}["nafdhnp"]})) {
            ${${"GLOBALS"}["xytqykr"]} = array();
            ${"GLOBALS"}["xfryqhn"] = "CI";
            ${"GLOBALS"}["dodvkwotq"] = "list";
            ${${"GLOBALS"}["xfryqhn"]} = &get_instance();
            ${"GLOBALS"}["ktmlpy"] = "list";
            ${${"GLOBALS"}["dodvkwotq"]} = $CI->db->query("SELECT parentsarray FROM category where id='" . intval(${${"GLOBALS"}["nafdhnp"]}) . "'")->result();
            return ${${"GLOBALS"}["ktmlpy"]}[0]->parentsarray;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
if (!function_exists("gen_backlinks")) {
    function gen_backlinks($parentsArray)
    {
        $uasqrylb = "list";
        ${${"GLOBALS"}["tmjgwmr"]} = array();
        ${$uasqrylb} = explode("||", ${${"GLOBALS"}["zdvwmpshlpn"]});
        ${"GLOBALS"}["ubyeqznyzznv"] = "list";
        ${${"GLOBALS"}["rvkxbu"]} = 0;
        foreach (${${"GLOBALS"}["ubyeqznyzznv"]} as ${${"GLOBALS"}["jmjkcwrtoljb"]}) {
            if (!empty(${${"GLOBALS"}["jmjkcwrtoljb"]})) {
                $nmneagq = "url";
                ${"GLOBALS"}["bcxbypxeen"] = "bklnk_i";
                $uoikacjkerm = "bklnk_i";
                $cpdpmg = "i";
                ${${"GLOBALS"}["mmbijie"]} = explode("|", ${${"GLOBALS"}["jmjkcwrtoljb"]});
                ${${"GLOBALS"}["tmjgwmr"]}[${$cpdpmg}]["url"] = ${${"GLOBALS"}["bcxbypxeen"]}[0];
                ${$nmneagq}[${${"GLOBALS"}["rvkxbu"]}]["title"] = ${$uoikacjkerm}[1];
                ${${"GLOBALS"}["rvkxbu"]}++;
            }
        }
        return ${${"GLOBALS"}["tmjgwmr"]};
    }
}
if (!function_exists("formatSize")) {
    function formatSize($size, $round = 2)
    {
        $hcslowfma = "i";
        ${"GLOBALS"}["xourqveliyv"] = "total";
        $hvgwqobosg = "size";
        ${"GLOBALS"}["qsflinyhe"] = "i";
        ${${"GLOBALS"}["vsgjwjgohjuo"]} = array("Byts", "kb", "mb", "gb", "tb");
        $wntpvqhqlmv = "i";
        ${${"GLOBALS"}["bvfnpllyxgs"]} = count(${${"GLOBALS"}["vsgjwjgohjuo"]}) - 1;
        for (
            ${${"GLOBALS"}["qsflinyhe"]} = 0;
            ${${"GLOBALS"}["sknxttw"]} > 1024 && ${$wntpvqhqlmv} < ${${"GLOBALS"}["xourqveliyv"]};
            ${$hcslowfma}++
        ) ${${"GLOBALS"}["sknxttw"]} /= 1024;
        return round(${$hvgwqobosg}, ${${"GLOBALS"}["qyjncgibsx"]}) . " " . ${${"GLOBALS"}["vsgjwjgohjuo"]}[${${"GLOBALS"}["rvkxbu"]}];
    }
}
if (!function_exists("related_files")) {
    function related_files($id)
    {
        ${"GLOBALS"}["shzpyrjkmbl"] = "id";
        ${${"GLOBALS"}["xytqykr"]} = array();
        ${"GLOBALS"}["dfgopqjwn"] = "list";
        ${${"GLOBALS"}["dfmnkulxo"]} = &get_instance();
        ${"GLOBALS"}["hknilofbisd"] = "list";
        ${${"GLOBALS"}["hknilofbisd"]} = $CI->db->query('SELECT * FROM files where status="A" AND category_id="' . ${${"GLOBALS"}["shzpyrjkmbl"]} . '" ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 4')->result();
        return ${${"GLOBALS"}["dfgopqjwn"]};
    }
}
if (!function_exists("valid_sort")) {
    function valid_sort($type)
    {
        $ldjkhhddt = "t";
        ${${"GLOBALS"}["jbdilpns"]} = array("n2o", "o2n", "a2z", "z2a");
        if (in_array(${${"GLOBALS"}["ryjuqyuyytv"]}, ${$ldjkhhddt})) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
if (!function_exists("gen_thumb")) {
    function gen_thumb($id, $type = 'category')
    {
        $qucmxyqljd = "type";
        ${"GLOBALS"}["imghhrgupt"] = "location";
        $omuplvoslpmy = "add";
        ${${"GLOBALS"}["dfmnkulxo"]} = &get_instance();
        ${$omuplvoslpmy} = NULL;
        if (${${"GLOBALS"}["ryjuqyuyytv"]} == "files") {
            ${${"GLOBALS"}["rxsfphe"]} = "extension,";
        }
        ${${"GLOBALS"}["rvkxbu"]} = $CI->db->query('SELECT ' . ${${"GLOBALS"}["rxsfphe"]} . 'thumb FROM ' . ${$qucmxyqljd} . ' where id="' . intval(${${"GLOBALS"}["nafdhnp"]}) . '"')->result();
        $lsdbpiatqwij = "i";
        $ueunzpyjl = "location";
        ${${"GLOBALS"}["imghhrgupt"]} = "/data/thumb/" . ${${"GLOBALS"}["rvkxbu"]}[0]->thumb;
        if (file_exists($CI->config->item("root") . ${$ueunzpyjl}) && !empty(${$lsdbpiatqwij}[0]->thumb)) {
            return ${${"GLOBALS"}["nwisdeafetc"]};
        } else {
            ${"GLOBALS"}["ulcufcpcs"] = "type";
            ${"GLOBALS"}["uzqvpsp"] = "default";
            if (${${"GLOBALS"}["ulcufcpcs"]} == "files") {
                $lfguonfeu = "i";
                $mibotqeoijf = "default";
                ${$mibotqeoijf} = "/images/" . strtolower(${$lfguonfeu}[0]->extension) . ".png";
            } else {
                $lynyycjn = "default";
                ${$lynyycjn} = "/images/folder.png";
            }
            return ${${"GLOBALS"}["uzqvpsp"]};
        }
    }
}
if (!function_exists("cat_name")) {
    function cat_name($id)
    {
        $giukqtxnk = "CI";
        ${$giukqtxnk} = &get_instance();
        $CI->db->select("category_name")->where("id", intval(${${"GLOBALS"}["nafdhnp"]}));
        ${${"GLOBALS"}["xytqykr"]} = $CI->db->get("category")->result();
        return ${${"GLOBALS"}["xytqykr"]}[0]->category_name;
    }
}
if (!function_exists("usable")) {
    function usable($file, $search = false)
    {
        $jologlnkv = "file";
        ${"GLOBALS"}["spmqsfqbs"] = "file";
        ${"GLOBALS"}["npjjknqr"] = "file";
        $kcvqjwek = "file";
        $mulxze = "file";
        ${"GLOBALS"}["izrliayvss"] = "file";
        ${"GLOBALS"}["mvxnirnhlb"] = "file";
        ${${"GLOBALS"}["esfuxfpwsnx"]} = str_replace("%20", "_", ${${"GLOBALS"}["esfuxfpwsnx"]});
        $loxmny = "file";
        ${${"GLOBALS"}["esfuxfpwsnx"]} = str_replace("%2B", "_", ${$jologlnkv});
        ${${"GLOBALS"}["esfuxfpwsnx"]} = str_replace("+", "_", ${${"GLOBALS"}["esfuxfpwsnx"]});
        $xijzyibpyd = "search";
        $uppxpr = "file";
        ${${"GLOBALS"}["mvxnirnhlb"]} = str_replace("+", "_", ${$kcvqjwek});
        ${${"GLOBALS"}["esfuxfpwsnx"]} = str_replace(",", "_", ${${"GLOBALS"}["esfuxfpwsnx"]});
        ${"GLOBALS"}["tnzpvrbujnp"] = "file";
        ${${"GLOBALS"}["spmqsfqbs"]} = str_replace(" ", "_", ${$uppxpr});
        $qbgccaljthxa = "ext";
        ${$mulxze} = str_replace("__", "_", ${${"GLOBALS"}["esfuxfpwsnx"]});
        ${$loxmny} = str_replace("___", "_", ${${"GLOBALS"}["esfuxfpwsnx"]});
        if (${$xijzyibpyd}) {
            return ${${"GLOBALS"}["esfuxfpwsnx"]};
        }
        ${"GLOBALS"}["abhdicakggn"] = "file";
        ${${"GLOBALS"}["otzvpmqy"]} = end(explode(".", ${${"GLOBALS"}["npjjknqr"]}));
        ${${"GLOBALS"}["dfmnkulxo"]} = &get_instance();
        ${${"GLOBALS"}["tnzpvrbujnp"]} = str_ireplace("." . ${${"GLOBALS"}["otzvpmqy"]}, null, ${${"GLOBALS"}["abhdicakggn"]}) . $CI->config->item("hide_sitename") . "." . ${$qbgccaljthxa};
        return ${${"GLOBALS"}["izrliayvss"]};
    }
}
function type($type)
{
    ${"GLOBALS"}["vhybszwsryb"] = "type";
    ${"GLOBALS"}["rarxksqbgj"] = "type";
    ${"GLOBALS"}["bkzqcvess"] = "type";
    ${"GLOBALS"}["lfnroekm"] = "type";
    $cbetfqulo = "type";
    $wxtqpltrphnx = "type";
    ${"GLOBALS"}["gqwiwqknm"] = "type";
    ${"GLOBALS"}["gookhsq"] = "type";
    $vbvctwvvxymh = "type";
    $jkjhtgvf = "type";
    ${"GLOBALS"}["uaslhycthx"] = "type";
    $wxbkbld = "type";
    ${"GLOBALS"}["uvmlvvfey"] = "type";
    $jrgedmgmw = "type";
    ${"GLOBALS"}["rynxfg"] = "type";
    $mengicwcg = "type";
    $mqmvylt = "type";
    ${"GLOBALS"}["efxeiewxxk"] = "type";
    ${"GLOBALS"}["ygpbxh"] = "type";
    $kjvkpsiw = "type";
    $iewfplshuj = "type";
    ${"GLOBALS"}["yvxvxcsoop"] = "type";
    ${"GLOBALS"}["jvqmoqq"] = "type";
    $xcmmwfzpk = "type";
    ${"GLOBALS"}["steapac"] = "type";
    if (!${${"GLOBALS"}["ryjuqyuyytv"]}) ${${"GLOBALS"}["ryjuqyuyytv"]} = "Folder";
    elseif (${$wxtqpltrphnx} == "jpg") ${${"GLOBALS"}["ryjuqyuyytv"]} = "wallpaper";
    elseif (${${"GLOBALS"}["ryjuqyuyytv"]} == "jpeg") ${${"GLOBALS"}["ryjuqyuyytv"]} = "wallpaper";
    elseif (${$vbvctwvvxymh} == "jpe") ${${"GLOBALS"}["lfnroekm"]} = "wallpaper";
    elseif (${${"GLOBALS"}["ryjuqyuyytv"]} == "png") ${$jkjhtgvf} = "wallpaper";
    elseif (${${"GLOBALS"}["uaslhycthx"]} == "mp3") ${${"GLOBALS"}["ryjuqyuyytv"]} = "Music";
    elseif (${${"GLOBALS"}["ryjuqyuyytv"]} == "wav") ${${"GLOBALS"}["uvmlvvfey"]} = "Music";
    elseif (${${"GLOBALS"}["gqwiwqknm"]} == "amr") ${${"GLOBALS"}["ryjuqyuyytv"]} = "Music";
    elseif (${${"GLOBALS"}["ryjuqyuyytv"]} == "3gp") ${${"GLOBALS"}["rynxfg"]} = "Video";
    elseif (${${"GLOBALS"}["bkzqcvess"]} == "mp4") ${${"GLOBALS"}["ryjuqyuyytv"]} = "Video";
    elseif (${$wxbkbld} == "avi") ${$cbetfqulo} = "Video";
    elseif (${${"GLOBALS"}["ryjuqyuyytv"]} == "flv") ${${"GLOBALS"}["ryjuqyuyytv"]} = "Video";
    elseif (${${"GLOBALS"}["ryjuqyuyytv"]} == "zip") ${${"GLOBALS"}["ryjuqyuyytv"]} = "Compressed File";
    elseif (${$mengicwcg} == "rar") ${${"GLOBALS"}["vhybszwsryb"]} = "Winrar File";
    elseif (${${"GLOBALS"}["ryjuqyuyytv"]} == "psd") ${${"GLOBALS"}["gookhsq"]} = "Photoshop Document";
    elseif (${${"GLOBALS"}["ryjuqyuyytv"]} == "pdf") ${$mqmvylt} = "Portable Document";
    elseif (${${"GLOBALS"}["rarxksqbgj"]} == "exe") ${${"GLOBALS"}["ryjuqyuyytv"]} = "Windows";
    elseif (${${"GLOBALS"}["ryjuqyuyytv"]} == "nth") ${${"GLOBALS"}["ryjuqyuyytv"]} = "Nokia Theme";
    elseif (${${"GLOBALS"}["efxeiewxxk"]} == "thm") ${${"GLOBALS"}["ygpbxh"]} = "Theme";
    elseif (${${"GLOBALS"}["ryjuqyuyytv"]} == "sis") ${$kjvkpsiw} = "Sybmian";
    elseif (${${"GLOBALS"}["ryjuqyuyytv"]} == "sisx") ${${"GLOBALS"}["yvxvxcsoop"]} = "Symbian";
    elseif (${${"GLOBALS"}["ryjuqyuyytv"]} == "jar") ${${"GLOBALS"}["jvqmoqq"]} = "Java";
    elseif (${$iewfplshuj} == "apk") ${$xcmmwfzpk} = "Android";
    elseif (${$jrgedmgmw} == "txt") ${${"GLOBALS"}["steapac"]} = "Text File";
    return trim(ucfirst(${${"GLOBALS"}["ryjuqyuyytv"]}));
}
function special($ext)
{
    $mcnrhr = "ext";
    ${${"GLOBALS"}["otzvpmqy"]} = strtolower(${$mcnrhr});
    ${"GLOBALS"}["mavswgubci"] = "use";
    $ufgabfxgnyg = "ext";
    ${"GLOBALS"}["skhdssdwoap"] = "ext";
    $ogvetztp = "ext";
    ${"GLOBALS"}["owdljbbqcm"] = "ext";
    $fovuklxwtgk = "ext";
    $rkburkngjkke = "use";
    if ((type(${$ufgabfxgnyg})) == "Wallpaper") ${${"GLOBALS"}["mavswgubci"]} = "gen_image_preview";
    elseif ((type(${${"GLOBALS"}["otzvpmqy"]})) == "Music") ${${"GLOBALS"}["pdicsfrvpn"]} = "gen_mp3_tags";
    elseif ((type(${${"GLOBALS"}["skhdssdwoap"]})) == "Video") ${${"GLOBALS"}["pdicsfrvpn"]} = "gen_video_preview";
    elseif ((type(${${"GLOBALS"}["owdljbbqcm"]})) == "Nokia Theme") ${${"GLOBALS"}["pdicsfrvpn"]} = "gen_nth_preview";
    elseif ((type(${$ogvetztp})) == "Theme") ${${"GLOBALS"}["pdicsfrvpn"]} = "gen_thm_preview";
    elseif ((type(${$fovuklxwtgk})) == "Java") ${$rkburkngjkke} = "gen_jar_preview";
    return ${${"GLOBALS"}["pdicsfrvpn"]};
}
function scan_folder($dir)
{
    $mudatbwa = "it";
    ${"GLOBALS"}["cnkuqgu"] = "it";
    $kkniidcteh = "file";
    ${$mudatbwa} = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(${${"GLOBALS"}["njfqrtm"]});
    $lnontueguh = "it";
    ${${"GLOBALS"}["cnkuqgu"]} = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(${$lnontueguh}, RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);
    $gznrfesuj = "it";
    ${"GLOBALS"}["nqwwrae"] = "return";
    foreach (${$gznrfesuj} as ${$kkniidcteh}) {
        ${"GLOBALS"}["fhxoccbtymnh"] = "link";
        ${"GLOBALS"}["yjnsycm"] = "link";
        ${"GLOBALS"}["pxrjxlbimpv"] = "dir";
        ${"GLOBALS"}["czlnycwytxmk"] = "return";
        ${${"GLOBALS"}["yjnsycm"]} = str_replace("\"", "/", $file->getPathname());
        $okouvdpaw = "link";
        ${${"GLOBALS"}["nsppyylnqkk"]} = str_replace(${${"GLOBALS"}["pxrjxlbimpv"]}, "", ${${"GLOBALS"}["fhxoccbtymnh"]});
        if ("." === $file->getBasename() || ".." === $file->getBasename()) continue;
        if ($file->isDir()) ${${"GLOBALS"}["czlnycwytxmk"]}["folder"][] = ${$okouvdpaw};
        else ${${"GLOBALS"}["ypbgqag"]}["file"][] = ${${"GLOBALS"}["nsppyylnqkk"]};
    }
    return ${${"GLOBALS"}["nqwwrae"]};
}
function c_f_e($file_name)
{
    $qmhozfh = "ext";
    ${"GLOBALS"}["qkmucueqhr"] = "ext";
    ${"GLOBALS"}["fgeuyyq"] = "exhibit_arr";
    $frdmvaw = "exhibit_arr";
    ${$frdmvaw} = array("exe", "php", "asp", "aspx", "jsp", "js", "php3", "php5", "html", "xhtml", ".htaccess");
    ${$qmhozfh} = end(explode(".", ${${"GLOBALS"}["yqyebcv"]}));
    if (in_array(${${"GLOBALS"}["qkmucueqhr"]}, ${${"GLOBALS"}["fgeuyyq"]})) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return ${${"GLOBALS"}["otzvpmqy"]};
    }
}
if (!function_exists("list_total_files")) {
    function list_total_files()
    {
        $hwpauvh = "list";
        ${${"GLOBALS"}["xytqykr"]} = array();
        ${${"GLOBALS"}["dfmnkulxo"]} = &get_instance();
        ${$hwpauvh} = $CI->db->get("files")->num_rows();
        return ${${"GLOBALS"}["xytqykr"]};
    }
}
if (!function_exists("list_total_downloads")) {
    function list_total_downloads()
    {
        ${"GLOBALS"}["vwywgmudqi"] = "list";
        ${${"GLOBALS"}["vwywgmudqi"]} = array();
        ${${"GLOBALS"}["dfmnkulxo"]} = &get_instance();
        ${${"GLOBALS"}["xytqykr"]} = $CI->db->select_sum("download")->get("files")->result();
        return ${${"GLOBALS"}["xytqykr"]}[0]->download;
    }
}
```